# AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute '_children'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following code :

```
def result_saml_decoded(result_saml):
"""Illustrate to result saml decoded value as response in a string.

:param result_saml:results saml decoded
:return:return principle_arn, resultsamldecoded, role_arns

"""
result_saml_decoded = base64.b64decode(result_saml)
root = ET.fromstring(result_saml_decoded)
principle_arns, role_arns = [], []
inner_saml_tag = [saml2 for saml2 in root._children if 'Assertion' in saml2.tag]
attribute_saml_tag = [saml_tag for saml_tag in inner_saml_tag[0]._children
                      if 'AttributeStatement' in saml_tag.tag]
for inner_saml_tag in attribute_saml_tag[0]._children:
    if 'uri' in inner_saml_tag.get('NameFormat'):
            for saml_data in inner_saml_tag._children:
                parts = saml_data.text.split(',')
                principle_arns.append(parts[0])
                role_arns.append(parts[1])

return principle_arns, role_arns
```

which works in python 2.7 but fails in python 3.6 with :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/Users/kaulk/sandbox/oktapod1/oktapod/helpers.py", line 135, in 
>        assume_role
>        principle_arns, role_arns = result_saml_decoded(resultsaml)
>        File "/Users/kaulk/sandbox/oktapod1/oktapod/helpers.py", line 188, in 
>        result_saml_decoded
>        **inner_saml_tag = [saml2 for saml2 in root._children if 'Assertion' in 
>        saml2.tag]
>        AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 
>        '_children'**

what am I supposed to use for code that is supposed to be compatible with py27 and 36 ?

Comment: Things starting with underscore are private and it is a code smell when you need to use them. It means you are not using the API as you should, and you are vulnerable to innerworkings change, which you just discovered. So find out how to do `root._children` using the proper methods of the API you are using.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I see it for py 3.6 as well (same code) : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L175

Comment: You did not read what I wrote: `_children` is private to the library, you should not reference it. This is poor API use.  Read below from your link the `getchildren` method and its deprecation warning that clearly show you how to use the API, which is **NOT** by using `_children` directly...